# Google Visualization CategoryFilter for a date type

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have a table that contains a filter for `myDate` and `partCategory`.  My example data set contains one date Jan 1, 2020.  The `CategoryFilter` is displaying Jan 1, 2020 multiple times. The other `CategoryFilter` for part category displays correctly with a single value matching the data table.

How do I modify `myDate` so that is works like `partCategory`?

Thanks as always!

```js
// Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart', 'table', 'gauge', 'controls']
});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(gChart0);

function gChart0() {
  drawChart();
}

function drawChart() {

  var result = [{
    "myDate": new Date(2020, 0, 1),
    "partId": '1234567890xxx',
    "partCategory": 'ABC',
    "someNumber": 0
  }, {
    "myDate": new Date(2020, 0, 1),
    "partId": '1234567890yyy',
    "partCategory": 'ABC',
    "someNumber": 0
  }, {
    "myDate":new Date(2020, 0, 1),
    "partId": '1234567890111',
    "partCategory": 'ABC',
    "someNumber": 0
  }];

  //Create DataTable
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Calendar Date');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Part Id');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Part Category');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Some Number');

  var dataArray = [];
  $.each(result, function(i, obj) {
    dataArray.push([
      obj.myDate,
      obj.partId,
      obj.partCategory,
      obj.someNumber
    ]);
  });
  data.addRows(dataArray);

  //Options

  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('div_dashboard'));

  var categoryPicker1 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
    containerId: 'div_categoryPicker1',
    options: {
      filterColumnIndex: 0,
      matchType: 'any',
      ui: {
        labelStacking: 'vertical',
        allowTyping: false,
        allowMultiple: false,
        allowNone: true
      }
    }
  });

  var categoryPicker2 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
    containerId: 'div_categoryPicker2',
    options: {
      filterColumnIndex: 2,
      matchType: 'any',
      ui: {
        labelStacking: 'vertical',
        allowTyping: false,
        allowMultiple: false,
        allowNone: true
      }
    }
  });

  var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'div_table',
    options: {
      width: '100%',
      height: 'auto',
      page: 'enable',
      pageSize: '15',
      sort: 'enable',
      allowHtml: true
    }
  });

  dashboard.bind([categoryPicker1, categoryPicker2], [table]);
  dashboard.draw(data);

} //END  function drawChart()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div id="div_dashboard"></div><br />
<div id="div_categoryPicker1"></div><br />
<div id="div_categoryPicker2"></div><br />
<div id="div_table"></div><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

on the `myDate` category filter,
you can use the `values` option.
this will override the available values from the data table.

to provide the values, you can use data table method --> `getDistinctValues(columnIndex)`

here, we set the available values to the distinct list of dates in the data table column.

```
var categoryPicker1 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
  controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
  containerId: 'div_categoryPicker1',
  options: {
    filterColumnIndex: 0,
    matchType: 'any',
    ui: {
      labelStacking: 'vertical',
      allowTyping: false,
      allowMultiple: false,
      allowNone: true
    },
    values: data.getDistinctValues(0)  // <-- set values
  }
});
```

see following working snippet...

```js
// Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart', 'table', 'gauge', 'controls']
});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(gChart0);

function gChart0() {
  drawChart();
}

function drawChart() {

  var result = [{
    "myDate": new Date(2020, 0, 1),
    "partId": '1234567890xxx',
    "partCategory": 'ABC',
    "someNumber": 0
  }, {
    "myDate": new Date(2020, 0, 1),
    "partId": '1234567890yyy',
    "partCategory": 'ABC',
    "someNumber": 0
  }, {
    "myDate":new Date(2020, 0, 1),
    "partId": '1234567890111',
    "partCategory": 'ABC',
    "someNumber": 0
  }];

  //Create DataTable
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Calendar Date');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Part Id');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Part Category');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Some Number');

  var dataArray = [];
  $.each(result, function(i, obj) {
    dataArray.push([
      obj.myDate,
      obj.partId,
      obj.partCategory,
      obj.someNumber
    ]);
  });
  data.addRows(dataArray);

  //Options

  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('div_dashboard'));

  var categoryPicker1 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
    containerId: 'div_categoryPicker1',
    options: {
      filterColumnIndex: 0,
      matchType: 'any',
      ui: {
        labelStacking: 'vertical',
        allowTyping: false,
        allowMultiple: false,
        allowNone: true
      },
      values: data.getDistinctValues(0)
    }
  });

  var categoryPicker2 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
    containerId: 'div_categoryPicker2',
    options: {
      filterColumnIndex: 2,
      matchType: 'any',
      ui: {
        labelStacking: 'vertical',
        allowTyping: false,
        allowMultiple: false,
        allowNone: true
      }
    }
  });

  var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'div_table',
    options: {
      width: '100%',
      height: 'auto',
      page: 'enable',
      pageSize: '15',
      sort: 'enable',
      allowHtml: true
    }
  });

  dashboard.bind([categoryPicker1, categoryPicker2], [table]);
  dashboard.draw(data);

} //END  function drawChart()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div id="div_dashboard"></div><br />
<div id="div_categoryPicker1"></div><br />
<div id="div_categoryPicker2"></div><br />
<div id="div_table"></div><br />
```